I cant deploy my maui app to ios due to codesigning
for some days now I haven't been able to get an archive of my app and it has completely halted business. The issue arose randomly when one day I stopped being able to publish my app on vs code by pairing to the mac. Since then I have tried every single thing I could read online and whichever direction I took I end up with the same ending.
Currently when I try to publish with commandline I get:

error : Code signing must be enabled to create an Xcode archive.

and when I publish with VS 2022:

Cannot create an IOS archive 'AteshgahMAUI.Mobile'. Process cannot be
executed on XMA server. arch exited with code 1. actool exited with
code 1. Asset catalogs are not available for the iOS platform.

when I do it through the commandline binary-log says:
Task "ComputeCodesignItems" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(IsMacEnabled)' == 'true') was evaluated as ('false' == 'true').
Task "Codesign" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(IsMacEnabled)' == 'true') was evaluated as ('false' == 'true').[1]

I have dotnet version 9.0.1 VS 2022 version 17.12.2. My mac is verions 15 and XCode 16.1 . I have connected to my mac from vs and when I do it with commandline I have this setup in my csproj:
    <CodesignKey>Apple Distribution:xxx</CodesignKey>
    <CodesignProvision>xxx</CodesignProvision>
    <ArchiveOnBuild>true</ArchiveOnBuild>
    <TcpPort>58181</TcpPort>
    <ServerAddres>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</ServerAddres>
    <ServerUser>xxx</ServerUser>
    <ServerPassword>xxx</ServerPassword>

This is all the diagnostic data I can get and research upon and I am very much so stuck trying to publish an update what direction can I take? is there anyone else facing this issue?

